# Simple loading time series and plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dataset, time-series

Being a beginner with python, I am very frustrated because after hours of research I can not find a solution for reading+plotting time serieses in python which could be done in matlab, R or gnuplot in 1 minute.

Data file:

```
# id  date                value1  quality anothervalue value2
   1  2011-05-19_16:30:19  974.3  3_1x    NODATA        10E-4
...
```

I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series, DataFrame, Panel
import matplotlib as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
a,b,c,d,e,f = np.loadtxt("dataset.dat", unpack=True,
    converters={ 1: mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') })
plt.plot_date(x=b, y=c)
plt.show()
```

Python keeps failing because it tries to automatically convert the data into float. So I tried to use the converters, but it fails for the other columns. No plot at all.

- how do I tell python to ignore lines beginning with # ?
- do i have to convert everything by hand or can i just read in a dataset without conversion?
- how to finally plot value1 over datetime?
- can I tell python to interpret NODATA as a value without data? So it does not plot it?

Is python so badly documented that one could not google a solution after hours or did I just miss something really practically useful out there?

Comment: Your question is really about matplotlib - so if you tag it as such, you're probably more likely to get a response.

Comment: You'd better ask one question at a time, or question becomes too broad to be answered, and not very useful for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can achieve desired result with numpy, as it's not well suited for arrays of different types. But as you import pandas, you can use `pd.read_csv`:

```
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> s = """# id  date                value1  quality anothervalue value2
... 1  2011-05-19_16:30:19  974.3  3_1x    NODATA        10E-4"""
>>> pd.read_csv(StringIO(s[2:]), sep='\s+', 
...      date_parser=mdates.strpdate2num('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'), 
...      parse_dates=['date'])
   id          date  value1 quality anothervalue  value2
0   1  734276.68772   974.3    3_1x       NODATA       0
```